# What ways are there to integrate NuGet with Team Foundation Server 2012?

Tags: tfs, nuget

I would like to know what ways there are to integrate a project that is built on Team Foundation Server with NuGet.

In particular, I would be very interested in:

- Whether there exist TFS build tasks for NuGet-related purposes (packaging or publishing) (e.g. I have found nugetter, but it has not been updated since September 2011, and I wonder if it has been superseded by TFS 2012 functionality, or if it works with NuGet 2.x);
- Whether TFS bundles a NuGet server (I know it already bundles (its own version of) a symbolsource server);

Answer (score 1):

It is saddening how far behind the tools team lag after NuGet has been brought into the development environment as a first class citizen.

There is an [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f0145bdf-3bd8-46e6-b1ef-1a685d373ae8) for publishing NuGet package from TFS build.  But first class support of a build template that output NuGet packages and double TFS as a NuGet server [LIKE TEAMCITY](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/NuGet) would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little over broad, but nearly all the information I have is in the [ALM Rangers Branching and Merging Guide v2.1](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/96396). Download the All Guides and look at the "Advanced Version Control Guide.pdf".